# Error log showing errors but I see can't whats wrong?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

[image]

I'm getting all these messages but i have no idea why?

Previously, I've been using Win, but switched to Ubuntu. Installed everything properly and I can run all apps I write, but still getting these messages.

Eclipse works fine also.

Comment: Which SDK version have you installed on Ubuntu? You can check it in the android SDK Manager. Check its version was the same on Windows.

Comment: Same as one installed on Windows.